# OpenGraph does not display the image and details if you dont add http://

Tags: facebook-opengraph

Tested on slack. If you add a link

```
foobar.com
```

and that link has all the opengraph meta details it will not add the opengraph to the link added. I have to add `http://foobar.com` in order for it to work

Is there maybe a setting i am missing or is this default behavior?